# Grab custom view's children defined in XML and put into Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently I'm working on a custom view that has to define specific dialog content depending on the place that is used:

`main.xml`

```
<com.example.MyView>

    <TextView android:text="Hello from Dialog"/>

</com.example.MyView>
```

My `MyView` class inflates different layout:

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {

    public EntriesList(Context context) {
        super(context);

        inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this);
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        // builder.setView();
        // Set all children from `main.xml` - in this case `TextView`

        builder.create().show();
    }

}
```

`my_view.xml` contains a button that opens dialog:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <Button android:onClick="openDialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I prevent from rendering `TextView`, grab it and push into the `Dialog` view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I prevent from rendering TextView

set its visibility to `GONE`

> grab it and push into the Dialog view

assign it an `id` and use `findViewById` to retrieve the view. Assign it, call `removeView()` on `MyView` and assign it to the Dialog through `setView()`. Important is that you remove the view because the same instance can have only one parent.

As alternative you could provide the name of the layout you want to set to your dialog as tag of your `MyView`, retrieve it when the button is pressed, resolve its id, inflate it and call `setView` providing the inflated view as parameter